# Conversion of multi column to row with reference to first column?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, awk, grep

This is my file A

```
NoARTInfo_6 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g8589t1
NoARTInfo_6 alia_query_atg_all  alia|FBgn0028542
NoARTInfo_7 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g7396t1
NoARTInfo_7 alia_query_atg_all  alia|rmt0034647
WTCArcNu8_1 req_query_atg_all req|nbrL2EG020589
WTCArcNu21_1  hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g5599t1
WTCArcNu21_1  req_query_atg_all req|nbrL2EG004245
```

I want to convert the file into file B which looks like

```
NoARTInfo_6 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g8589t1 alia_query_atg_all alia|FBgn0028542
NoARTInfo_7 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g7396t1  alia_query_atg_all  alia|rmt0034647
WTCArcNu8_1 req_query_atg_all req|nbrL2EG020589
WTCArcNu21_1  hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g5599t1 req_query_atg_all  req|nbrL2EG004245
```

The first column has some repeated identifiers (here `NoARTInfo_6`, `NoARTInfo_7`, `NoARTInfo_6`) and some unique identifier (here `NoARTInfo_6`).

The second and third columns have their values.

If the first columns ids are repeated then they should be only one time in file B with all their values.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please show your code and describe the problem you are having

Answer (score 2):

This awk should work:

```
awk '!a[$1]{b[++n]=$1; a[$1]=$0; next} {k=$1; $1=""; a[k] = a[k] $0}
     END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[b[i]]}' file
NoARTInfo_6 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g8589t1 alia_query_atg_all alia|FBgn0028542
NoARTInfo_7 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g7396t1 alia_query_atg_all alia|rmt0034647
WTCArcNu8_1 req_query_atg_all req|nbrL2EG020589
WTCArcNu21_1  hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g5599t1 req_query_atg_all req|nbrL2EG004245
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
open (my $fh, "<", "fileA") or die $!;  #Open fileA in read mode
open (my $fh2, ">", "fileB") or die $!; #Open fileB in write mode
while(chomp(my $line=<$fh>)){
    my ($key, @values) = split / /, $line;
    if(exists $hash{$key}){
       my $ref_value = $hash{"$key"};
       push @values, @$ref_value;
       $hash{"$key"} = [@values];   
    }
     else{
       $hash{"$key"} = [@values];
    }
}
foreach(keys %hash){
    print $fh2 "$_ @{$hash{$_}}\n"; #Write to fileB
}
close($fh);
close($fh2);
```

---

Shorter:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# your code goes here
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
open (my $fh, "<", "fileA") or die $!;  #Open fileA in read mode
open (my $fh2, ">", "fileB") or die $!; #Open fileB in write mode
while(chomp(my $line = <$fh>)){
    my ($k, @vals) = split / /, $line;
    push @{ $hash{$k} }, @vals;
}
foreach(keys %hash){
    print $fh2 "$_ @{$hash{$_}}\n"; #Write to fileB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  my ($key, @list) = split;
  push(@keys, $key) if !defined $hash{$key};
  push(@{$hash{$key}}, @list);
}
foreach (@keys) {
  print join(' ', ($_, @{$hash{$_}})), "\n";
}
```

Output

```
./script.pl data
NoARTInfo_6 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g8589t1 alia_query_atg_all alia|FBgn0028542
NoARTInfo_7 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g7396t1 alia_query_atg_all alia|rmt0034647
WTCArcNu8_1 req_query_atg_all req|nbrL2EG020589
WTCArcNu21_1 hm_database_atg_all bil|qw_N_g5599t1 req_query_atg_all req|nbrL2EG004245
```

I'm not sure if the order of the lines is important but I preserved it in any case.